# SD card throughput on Linux machine

Tags: linux, embedded, android-sdcard, hard-drive

I'm trying to run a custom application on an embedded Linux platform (Linux 4.1). This application writes 1 MB of data continuously to the SD card (Sandisk UHS I class). The application uses an `fwrite()` call to write the data to the SD card.

Below are my observations when the SD card write throughput was monitored.

1. The average throughout is around 10 Mbytes per sec.
2. The instantaneous throughput (measured per 1 MB transfer) drops after every 50 MB data is written. The throughput drops as low as 200kbytes per sec.
3. I have tried using `write()` system call instead of `fwrite()`, with `O_SYNC` flag set. With this, the instantaneous throughput has increased to 1MBps.

The SD card spec says the minimum throughput supported is 10 MBps. Why does the instantaneous throughput drop?

Is this behaviour expected? What is limiting the instantaneous throughput?

My application requires minimum instantaneous throughput of 4MBps. What should I do?

Comment: Make sure your filesystem is truly aligned with the physical block size, make sure you write buffers exactly a physical block long, and make sure you have plenty of buffer memory to decouple the source from whatever the card's flash translation layer feels like doing.  Note that throughput of the SD interface is very distinct from write (commit) speed of a given card - you may get the data over there quickly, but it may take its own sweet time becoming ready for more.

Comment: Thanks Dan!  These things are already taken care, the physical block size is 512 and the write buffer is 1MB . I agree the speed will be less than what is specified by the vendor, still 200KB is very less.

Comment: "the physical block size is 512" no, it is most definitely not that small for any modern card.  Wherever you got that information, it is erroneous - it may reflect an *emulated* size rather than a physical one, and that is prime suspect for slowing.  You want to match both the block size, and make sure that the filesystem blocks are aligned with the physical ones, which can easily become an issue in casual format attempts.  You can probably afford a much larger buffer, too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the interface and the driver connecting your embedded linux device with the SD-card supports the throughput. (E.g. when it's connected via "Bitbanging" the throughput could be much less than what you expect).
2. Test the throughput with a well known tool (dd) and flush the cache before:
   sync; echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
   dd if=/dev/zero of= bs=500K count=2024
3. And finally please refer to: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32884/why-does-the-sd-card-random-write-performance-for-record-size-8-128-kb-drops-bel